# Considering a prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$. Show that for any pair of integers $(a,b)$, we can get $k,l$ having these properties

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Consider a prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$. Show that for any pair of integers $(a,b)$ such that p does not divide the gcd of $a$ and $b$, there exists $(k,l)∈ Z$ such that $ak-bl \equiv1 \pmod p$ and $al \equiv -bk \pmod p$.

My attempt:

Using the hint, I reduced the problem as follows-
"Prove that there exists some $r$ such that $r(a^2+b^2) \equiv 1 \pmod p$"
Now if I take $r=(a^2+b^2)^{p-2}$, then we get,
 $$(a^2+b^2)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$ 
and thats Euler's theorem. Only I need to prove that $$(a^2+b^2)^{p-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$ can not be true.

Comment: Try $(k,l)=(ra,-rb)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ok...a min

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I see that the second condition holds..but what about the first?

Comment: So your challenge is to prove there is a suitable $r$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown there exists some $r$ so that $p|r(a^2+b^2)-1$

Comment: Good ... you are making progress. Can you **prove** that such an $r$ exists?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I need your help

Comment: Please would you give any hint?

Comment: Anyone any hint?

Comment: If $p$ is 3 mod 4, then there is no square-root of -1 mod $p$.

Comment: @Aravind would you please explain?