# Prove that $p$ does not divide $a^2+b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a prime $p$ of the form $4k+3$ and a pair of integers $a,b$ such that $p$ does not divide the gcd of $a$ and $b$, prove that $p$ does not divide $a^2+b^2$.

This is an intermediate step of the following problem
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604791/considering-a-prime-p-of-the-form-4k3-show-that-for-any-pair-of-integers

I have no clue, so any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  show that under these conditions $a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod p$ would imply that $-1$ was a quadratic residue $\pmod p$.

Comment: @lulu Would you please explain...I am unable to get it

Comment: That hint is pretty much a complete solution.  Say $b$ is not divisible by $p$ (we know that at least one of $a,b$ is not divisible by $p$).   Then $a^2\equiv -b^2 \implies \left( ab^{-1} \right)^2\equiv -1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $p\mid a^2+b^2$ with $p\nmid a,b$. Write $$a^2\equiv -b^2\pmod{p}$$ and raise both sides to the $(p-1)/2$'th power. By Fermat this gives $$1\equiv a^{p-1}\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}b^{p-1}\equiv (-1)^{2k+1}\equiv -1 \pmod{p},$$
and this is clearly impossible for $p\ne 2$.

Comment: are we using the facts that  $p$ is of form $4k+3$?

Comment: yes, this was used in the last line, where we substitute $(p-1)/2=2k+1$.

Comment: And the gcd condition?

Comment: $p\nmid \mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$ if and only if $p\nmid a,b$ because $p$ is prime

Comment: no, take $p=3$ $a,b=6,4$

Comment: yes in general, but we are given that $p\mid a^2+b^2$ and so it follows easily $p\mid a$ implies $p \mid b$.

Comment: we are asked to prove that p does not divide $a^2+b^2$

Comment: Indeed, and the proof goes by contradiction

Comment: oh! I got it now